# I installed ubuntu 20.x, is it possible to encrypt my hard drive or this can only be done during installation?

Tags: encryption

I installed Ubuntu 20.x recently, but if I am keep this as my main operating system I would like to encrypt my hard drive contents in case of theft etc.

Is it possible to perform encryption at this point or this is something I have to do during the installation process?

Answer (score 0):

You can only encrypt the whole disk during installation but if you want to encrypt a certain amount of disk that contains your files except system files, you can do that.

Comment: you can get disk encryption tools from here. [ https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html ]

Comment: is that the preferred way to do it?  system files don't need encryption do they?

Comment: They can be encrypted though but not necessary.

Comment: You can just encrypt your files. If you want to encrypt your system files too then you need to reinstall your OS.

Comment: I want automatic encryption of the drive, not just a folder.

Comment: That's not possible. You need to reinstall your OS.